Can something escape from inside of a black hole's event horizon by putting a sufficiently large mass next to it?
As far as I know, a lot of the maths surrounding black holes basically assumes that the black hole is the only mass in the entire universe. But what if something has fallen into the event horizon of a black hole just under it's surface, and some other big enough mass is moved close enough. Would this then basically shrink the event horizon allowing whatever has fallen in to get out again in theory because the gravitational pull of the other mass competes with that of the black hole in the opposite direction?

No, it will do the opposite.

As observed from outside, nothing ever crosses the horizon, so there is nothing inside yet that could escape. Also, the horizon doesn’t shrink, but expands toward the approaching mass. This doesn’t make any difference though, because all objects near the horizon move along with it, so nothing crosses in or out anyway.

If the other mass is a sufficiently large black hole the event horizons merge as the black holes merge and the object might escape from the first hole into the second, but the object is still inside a merged event horizon., not withstanding safesphere's comment which I tend to agree with.

The event horizon is defined, based on the full structure of the spacetime (i.e., knowledge of the entire future and past history), to be the boundary of the region from which nothing can escape to infinity. So by definition, nothing can escape from inside the event horizon, irrespective of the circumstances. But there is no physics in this answer, only semantics. If your object could escape, then by definition, it was not inside the event horizon.
For an answer involving physics, perhaps you want to know instead whether a black hole's event horizon can shrink due to the influence of a nearby mass. An object that would be inside the event horizon of the unperturbed black hole might then find itself outside the event horizon of the perturbed system. The answer to this question is likely to be also no. The area of the event horizon, at least, is forbidden from shrinking by the second law of black hole thermodynamics.

The answer to "can something escape from inside a black hole's event horizon" is always "no", regardless of the means attempted. This is a matter of geometry. The spacetime geometry "inside" a black hole is such that all world lines go to the singularity. In effect trying to avoid the singularity is very much as futile as trying to avoid tomorrow.

Indeed, it is exactly as futile as trying to avoid tomorrow: In an appropriately chosen coordinate system, the radial coordinate takes the role of "time" for the region inside the horizon.
